# Sharing Links on Cloud

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, creative-cloud

I have an indesign file with 6 links. I just learned about the File>Package option of sending them to another editor. However, I am wondering if there is a feature in Adobe CC where we can save the linked files to the cloud so that they are always shared among the editors.

Comment: Hi Holly, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

If you save your package to a folder on the Creative Cloud, you can set "collaborators" to that folder to give your coworkers access to all its contents. Just make sure "**Copy Linked Graphics**" is checked before you save.